# Python web scraping : 503 Response with specific site (how come?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, ipython, python-requests

Experimenting with learning python and web scraping some web sites. Seeing what I can learn. I noticed [Amazon.com](http://amazon.com) would give me a `Response 503` unless I use a header attribute in my `SESSION.get()`.

But this does not work for [readcomiconline.to](http://readcomiconline.to) where I get a `Response 503` no matter what I try. Assuming this has to do with it's JavaScript preloader.

Any work around with this?

```
import requests 
urlAmazon = 'http://amazon.com'
urlComics = 'http://readcomiconline.to'
headerAgent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}
client = requests.session()

resultOne = client.get(urlAmazon)
print(resultOne) #<Response [503]>
resultOne = client.get(urlAmazon, headers=headerAgent)
print(resultOne) #<Response [200]>

resultTwo = client.get(urlComics)
print(resultTwo) #<Response [503]>
resultTwo = client.get(urlComics, headers=headerAgent)
print(resultTwo) #<Response [503]>
```

Tried using Selenium and still getting the 503 error. Any way around the javascript at all to do a proper web scrape?

```
import bs4, requests
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html

headerAgent = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'}

res = requests.get('http://readcomiconline.to/Comic/Saga/Issue-1 &readType=1',headers=headerAgent)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
comicElement = soup.find('table', {'class':'listing'})
```

Comment: You're right about the second site, it uses js to send verification to `/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl` and get cookies. You can either use `selenium` or reverse the js ( it's about 40 lines )

Comment: @t.m.adam Where did you go to find that info over javascript sending verification to `/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl`? (using Chrome DevTools?). I started messing a bit with Selenium (logging into a website and finding certain elements on the page). I'll dig more into this approach.

Comment: I use firefox with no-script

Comment: I tried using Selenium, but still running into the 503 issue. Stumped on if there is any other way to approach sites like this with web scraping.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing about selenium is it can emulate the actions executed by scripts using `execute_script('script')`. For sites whose contents are rendered by JS, the best way is to understand how JS renders the contents. Trace the XHR and check the responses to see if it returns the content you need.