# Skip waiting time using node-fetch

Tags: node.js, cheerio, node-fetch

I use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) and [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to craw data from a [comic website](http://readcomiconline.to/). I just use a simple code to display the body html like below:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = 'http://readcomiconline.to';

function getComic() {
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(body => console.log(body));
}

getComic();
```

The problem is this page use a javascript code that the client need to wait in 5 second before it redirect to the main page, so I cannot crawl anything before the main pages loaded.

How can I skip this time and starting to crawl data from the pages.

Thank you.

Comment: The loading screen only shows once though

Comment: @sorxrob Yes, I know it, but how can I skip that ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're going to need more than those 2 modules.

The website you're trying to scrape uses JS to send verification to `/cdn-cgi/l/chk_jschl` and get cookies. You can either use [selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium) or reverse the js.

More info here: [Python web scraping : 503 Response with specific site (how come?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44010838/python-web-scraping-503-response-with-specific-site-how-come?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need wait 5s, because it will run in browser.

You have form `#challenge-form`, use [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to get `url`, `method` and data(value of input) of form, and request it (save cookie).

You can use `devtool` (chrome, or something like that check form of request in browser).

This is project I try to login `facebook`: [index.js](https://github.com/Hongarc/fb-chat-emulator/blob/master/index.js), it may be help you.